# MySQL load data in-file and fgetcsv

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

I try a bit with CSV import methods. In the moment I use `fgetcsv` with each row validation and inserts, which works but is slow. So i thought to use load data `infile` instead.
The CSV is exported by excel with `;` as standard delimiter. Its from different users, so I cannot change this.

Problem is one column, which can contain HTML and also the use of ; in code.

When I use `fgetscv` with inserts I have no problems, identifying headers. But with load data in-file I get for sure problems with this delimiter.

This way i do this now:

```
while (($aCell = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

                    $num = count($aCell);

                    //Run through columns, build array
                    for ($a = 0; $a < $num; $a++) {

                        // IDENTIFY HEADERS
                        switch ($field[$a]) {

                            case ($field_name = "comlumn1"):
                                // DO SOME VALIDATION etc.
                                $array['column1'] =  $aCell[$a];
                                break;
                            case ($field_name = "comlumn2"):
                                // DO SOME VALIDATION etc.
                                $array['column2'] =  $aCell[$a];
                                break;

                            // AND SO ON
                        }   

                    }

                    // INSERT array in db for each row

                }
```

An example of the csv structure:

```
column1 column2
1       <p style="margin-top: 10;">...
```

When i use load data infile i get problems with column description cause of ";"

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/filepath/import.csv' INTO TABLE import_csv
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Which solutions I've got? 
One idea is to read out the lines by `fgetscv` first (like i do above) make an temp array with no validation and no inserts and then do a new implode with an other delimiter, so that i can use it in load data in-file.

I'm not sure if it is faster or really make sense than doing the whole thing with `fgetcsv`, remember the fact, that there will not be more than 1000 rows in CSV.

**EDIT**

My solution now is, as written above build an array and implode it with a new unique delimiter:

```
$fp = fopen("file.csv","w");
foreach((array)$oldarray as $val) {
    fwrite($fp,implode("*|*",$val)."\r\n");
}
fclose($fp);
```

With this unique delimiter i can use LOAD DATA INFILE with no problem.

Comment: Describe the problems you get... how do your headers appear in the csv file?

Comment: Please consider to post a sample from your file to illustrate your question.

Comment: hey guys i added some sample code. hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Show an example of the datafile to highlight your problem... if the problem is caused by the data itself, then that's what we need to see